# Android Auto Music app is not showing in "Android auto" app

Tags: android, media-player, auto

I did one music(streaming) application by using exoplayer. But this application need to support android auto too. For this I follow the android developer site.
https://developer.android.com/training/auto/audio/

In this they given one sample application.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer

For this sample, I configured **media-browser-simulator.apk** in my emulator. So this sample(UAMP) application working fine in emulator.

[image]

But when run this application in my device not working for auto, For this in my device(Marshmallow) i have installed android auto, In this android auto not showing this sample(UAMP) application.

[image]

So my questions are

1) Why this sample application not showing in my device. it is working in emulator.

2) Which procedure is correct emulator or device?

3) This sample application is developed by using kotlin, But need any java sample application.

So please guide me how to do this. Thanks to all for your support

Comment: Are you sure you have configured your [manifest permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/auto/audio/) correctly? From the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) you linked it looks like its missing the android auto permissions.

Comment: But the same application working fine in emulator

Comment: I have given permission, but not working

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable **Unknown sources** Android Auto app.

To do this follow the steps:

- Open "About" screen from side menu
- Click tree dots in top right corner
- Open "Developer settings"
- Enable "Unknown sources" (at the bottom of the list)

Check also [Run the DHU](https://developer.android.com/training/auto/testing/#running-dhu) section from [Test apps for Auto](https://developer.android.com/training/auto/testing).